# How can I ensure a juicy beef burger patty?

Tags: beef

Also tell if i need to mince the beef lumps before mincing the beef to make patties

Comment: Some idea of what you have previously tried would be good, to determine if you are having a specific problem.

Comment: Elendilthetall this is going to be my first attempt.no prior experience 

Answer (score 0):

Using a coarse grinder attachment. Take the meat straight from grinder, leaving it with the grain from grinder like a "log". Do not mix it up. Do not add any extra ingredients after grinding

If your grinder output is not very wide, make three or four "logs", and lay them parallel to each other to make a cluster

Cut the burger patties across the grain of the "log", and gently press the outside edge inward to hold the disc shape

Cook on high heat till rare or medium rare, and enjoy

Comment: What about the spices added to beef?

Comment: A true beef burger has nothing but salt and pepper added. Also, if you are cooking to rare or medium rare as TFD suggests, be _very_ sure of your source of meat.

Comment: @Tallal Hassan While you can add spices to the meat before grinding, it may burn or interfere with natural meat protein binding during the hot cooking step. Add spices and other things to other parts of the burger, typically in the sauce